# Can the spin connection be derived from a structure group reduction?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I understand from [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.01410) that reducing the structure group $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$ of the frame field $FX$ of a world manifold $X^4$ to the $O(4,\mathbb{R})$ group entails the Levi-Civita connection as the (unique torsion-free) connection that preserves the reduction.

Can we define the spin connection as a structure group reduction?